# Python - Parsing a text onto columns by the position of each item

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, bigdata

The Bovespa (brazilian stock exchange) offer a file with all the quotes in a timeframe. The file is too large, and each line are something like this real sample:

```html
012016010402AAPL34      010APPLE       DRN          R$  000000000415000000000042200000000004150000000000421300000000042080000000003950000000000435000005000000000000012500000000000052664400000000000000009999123100000010000000000000BRAAPLBDR004115
```

So, looking for the docs, I found that the column mapping is something like that:

- char 01 to 02: (int) type of register;
- char 03 to 10: (date) date of the stock quote info;
- char 11 to 12: (int) some kind of code;
- char 13 to 24: (str) the stock ticker;
- ....

I'm starting to study Python and trying to read a file which contains this data, and got each line sucessfull with this code:

```html
import pandas as pd
dataset1 = pd.read_table('bmfbovespaquotes/DemoCotacoesHistoricas12022003.txt')
```

I think that maybe this is a silly question, but I didn't find the solution already, so if you know a way to solve this, please share.

Thanks

Comment: use [read_fwf(filename, colspecs=...)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html)

Comment: you are welcome! Please post your solution as an answer - it might help others in future, especially those who will want to parse Bovespa (`brazilian stock exchange`) data

Answer (score 4):

You have a ***f***ixed **w**idth **f**ormat: this will do the trick.

```
pd.read_fwf(file_path, widths=[...], names=[...])
```

you should pass the list of widths, which in your case starts as `[2,8,2,10,...]` and the list of columns `['register','date','code','ticker',...]`