# Read a txt into a DataFrame with only field locations act as delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a txt file into a DataFrame using `pd.read_csv()`.

However I soon realized that I cannot use a simple delimiter. The txt file is formatted as shown below, each of the fields could contain a comma, space, or other characters that usually act as a delimiter.

The only way to separate the fields seems to be using the position provided in the picture.

I wonder if there's a way that I can perform the task?

Thanks!

[image]

Edit:
**An example line would be like**:

```
DIDIDI12354John, Doe                                                   @@47385y43785yHUIBBIBJIBIBUBK@@SUBUKBCSHB77                                    NUIKBHUS1234                                                  Unit 7                        45             NON'EXIST RD                                                          A
```

Comment: Can you show what your txt looks like?

Comment: Hi Prakash, thanks for answering! I have added an example line in the post.

Comment: At this is clearly no csv format, you should use you indices and lengths for reading, but not using `read_csv`. Look at [Parsing a text onto columns by the position of each item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563310/python-parsing-a-text-onto-columns-by-the-position-of-each-item).

Comment: Ah I see. I've never heard of read_fwf before. I'll have a look and thank you! 

Comment: See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67196527/pandas-read-text-file-slicing-columns-according-to-header/) for sample usage of `read_fwf()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read_fwf` to read your file and `colspecs` parameters like this:

```
positions = [1, 11, 71, 73, 74, 82, 86, 87, 91, 93, 97, 98, 99,
             100, 150, 160, 162, 212, 242, 257, 327, 328, 339, 348]
start = [0] + positions[1:]
stop = positions[1:] + [-1]

df = pd.read_fwf('file.txt', colspecs=list(zip(start, stop)), header=None)
```

```
>>> df.T  # transpose for a better display
                 0
0      DIDIDI12354
1        John, Doe
2               @@
3                4
4         7385y437
5             85yH
6                U
7             IBBI
8               BJ
9             IBIB
10               U
11               B
12               K
13  @@SUBUKBCSHB77
14      NUIKBHUS12
15              34
16             NaN
17          Unit 7
18              45
19    NON'EXIST RD
20               A
21             NaN
22             NaN
23             NaN
```